# El puerto 80, 443 de apache cambia cuando abro a mi proyecto en una pestaña del navegador, pero después de cerrar la pestaña vuelve a 80 de nuevo

Tags: php, apache

En la primera imagen se ve como ha iniciado correctamente apache en los puertos 80 y 443, ahora cuando ingreso al navegador y entro a ver el proyecto se cambia[[image: 1]

Como se ve, no carga y empieza a cambiar, no solo a esos puertos si no que cambia varias veces[image]

Tengo otro proyecto y cuando lo abro no pasa lo anterior.
Si ven la ultima imagen, si carga el proyecto pero no cambian los puertos[image]

No inicio MySQL ya que mi base de datos esta un servidor y no hay necesidad de iniciar el servicio.
Alguien que le ha pasado este problema?
Gracias de antemano por su tiempo.

Comment: Debo añadir que cambie el puerto 80 a 81 y cuando trate de iniciar el proyecto paso lo mismo, y con el otro proyecto no. Ayuda...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En [este enlace](https://community.apachefriends.org/f/viewtopic.php?p=197896&sid=df3bb64d241e7e17c754fa1982a0fc4c) puedes ver la respuesta que dieron en el foro de Apache:

> In short, that is normal.
>
> Apache listens for and accepts requests on ports 80 and 443 but it
> does not service requests on those ports. When you or others connect
> to your servers, they will be handled by other connections usually
> using high ports. The control panel just looks for all ports
> associated with a module. It is just picking up those client ports and
> the box to show all the ports is just not big enough to show them all.

Por tanto, Apache esta dando servicio por el puerto 80 y 433, por el resto no.

Comment: Pero, eso pasa solo con un proyecto ya que cuando inicio otros no pasa, que debería hacer?

Comment: En principio no tienes ningún problema porque no esta dando servicio por esos puertos, por lo que no hay problema. De todas formas tiene pinta de que esta tratando de conectarse con la base de datos remota. Puede ser que con el proyecto que no te pasa no se conecte a la base de datos ?